# Como hago para ir mostrando distintos resultados en el mismo Label?

Tags: python, tkinter

tengo el siguiente problema, desde un script con Tkinter generé un botón que ejecuta una función que a la vez ejecuta varios scripts. Necesito que un Label vaya informando de alguna manera que script se encuentra ejecutando.

El problema que tengo es que solo muestra el ultimo texto, los demás no aparecen.

Por ejemplo:

```
from tkinter import *
import os


def altas():

    var.set('Carga de tipos')
    resultado= Label(miFrame, height=10, width=100, state="disable",  textvariable = var).place(x=30, y=250)
    os.system("python Altas/put_tipos.py")
    var.set('Carga de temporadas')
    resultado= Label(miFrame, height=10, width=100, state="disable", textvariable = var).place(x=30, y=250)
    os.system("python Altas/put_temporadas.py")

raiz=Tk()

miFrame=Frame()

miFrame.pack()

botonAltas= Button (miFrame, text="Altas de Entidades",width=50, justify="center", command =altas).place (x=180, y=100)

var = StringVar()
var.set('Aguardando inicio de importación')
resultado= Label(miFrame, height=10, width=100, state="disable", textvariable = var).place(x=30, y=250)

raiz.mainloop()
```

Espero que se entienda la consulta, muchas gracias por cualquier tipo de ayuda!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explicación:**

Cuando usas `set()` estas reemplazando toda la información, y en cambio tu deseas que se añada.

**Solución:**

Debes concatenar el string que muestra el Label con el nuevo string y establecerlo en el Label.

```
# ...
var.set(var.get() + '\nCarga de tipos')
# ...
var.set(var.get() + '\nCarga de temporadas')
# ...
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta! perfecto! me sirve mucho ya que ahora me muestra la información de cada acción que ejecuta. Pero tengo un nuevo problema, porque me muestra todo junto cuando termina de ejecutar todas las acciones, y mi idea era que a medida que ejecuta cada script vaya mostrando un texto para que el usuario sepa que está haciendo el programa.

Comment: @GustavoVazquez ¿Cuanto tiempo demora en ejecutarse os.system()?, para serte sincero no veo adecuado llamar a otro archivo .py usando os.system() ya que me huele a un mal diseño...

Comment: Gracias de nuevo por tu ayuda, es muy probable que sea un mal diseño jaja hace poco que estoy con Python y es un trabajo de importación de entidades a un software a través de Api Rest. Te consulto para ver si me podes llegas a orientar, como llamarías a otro archivo .py sin usar el os.system ()? de verdad te agradezco mucho la ayuda! saludos!!

Comment: @GustavoVazquez 1) No has respondido mi pregunta 2) pues importandolo,..., python básico, ....

Comment: Respondiendo a tu pregunta, tarda 27 minutos por ahora y faltan mas entidades, ya que recorre 6 meses de comprobantes y entidades de un sistema de gestión. Por eso, si no muestro ningún mensaje al usuario, va a parecer que se congelo la aplicación. Por otro lado, ya probé importando (de hecho fue lo primero que hice) pero fue peor la perfomance. Gracias igual por tus respuestas.

Comment: @GustavoVazquez si tienes una tarea que bloquea el hilo donde se ejecuta el programa entonces deberias ejecutar esa tarea en otro hilo, te recomiendo revisar el modulo threading de python

Comment: Ok, lo voy a revisar. Gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: @GustavoVazquez si te das cuando el tiempo que demora en ejecutarse `os.system()` esta fuera del tema ya que tu pregunta se centra en solo añadir más texto en el Label por lo que considero que mi respuesta es válida, y si tu lo consideras asi deberias marcar mi respuesta como correcta, si no sabes como hacerlo entonces revisa el [tour]

Comment: perdón no sabía como hacerlo, de hecho desde el principio había dicho que era buena tu respuesta.

Comment: @GustavoVazquez tambien deberias leer [ask] y [answer]